# How to upload the download files into dropbox in Xamarin forms IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, dropbox

In my XAMARIN forms Application in the IOS, I wanted to upload the locally downloaded files into a dropbox. I use Dropbox Core API iOS SDK component for this.([by following this article](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/dropboxcoreapiios)).I successfully linked the dropbox account with the App using the dependency service

```
if (!Session.SharedSession.IsLinked)
{
 UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
 UIViewController viewController = window.RootViewController;
 Session.SharedSession.LinkFromController(viewController);
}
```

It creates the folder Apps/ApplicationName in the dropbox. Then I try to upload a local download file into dropbox wth an another dependency service using below code

```
var restClient = new RestClient(Session.SharedSession);
string dropboxPath = Session.RootDropbox;
restClient.UploadFile(filename, dropboxPath, null, localPath);
```

filename is name of the file, dropboxPath = dropbox and localPath like as

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4DF47BF5-3A0E-4177-A48E-0D3C245774F1/Documents.

Nothing will be upload after this. Is it a correct way of approach? Please suggest me a solution

Comment: Are you getting an error, or does nothing happen at all? Did you implement `FileUploaded` and `LoadFileFailed`? Also, make sure your `restClient` isn't going out of scope.

Comment: In addition, note that this SDK uses Dropbox API v1, which is deprecated: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/ You should migrate to API v2 whenever possible.